# JNI and thread unsafe initialization

Tags: java-native-interface

Suppose I am writing a JNI binding to a C library, which requires an initialization function to be called that isn't thread-safe.  Given that the JVM doesn't serialize calls to JNI_OnLoad, how can I avoid racing against someone else's library that also binds to my library?

Comment: You could write your own library, with the same name. Implement each API by simply calling the legacy library. Add thread safety in your own initialization function.